# Function returning

Tags: flash, string, function, actionscript

Why does this program always output the text for "future" from function year()?

In this case, with b+c equaling 56, var year should fall under (b+c) > 0 && (b+c) < 1000) and return "roman", but it instead returns "future"...

I got this to successfully work if I add this:

```
var period:String = (year(b,c));
```

and in my body function, make the conditionals check the period. For example

```
if (period == "future")
```

but I don't understand why I need to do this. I am returning a string, why do I have to set another variable? There is no compiler errors so clearly its not syntactical?

```
var a:String = "Tim";
var b:int = 50; //CHANGE TO ANY INT YOU WANT
var c:int = 6; //CHANGE TO ANY INT YOU WANT
var d:String = "Kyle";
var sum:int = b+c;

function friend(d:String, a:String):String
{
    return d+" and "+a;
}

function year(b:int, c:int):String
{
    if( (b+c) > 2000 )
        return "future";
    else if( (b+c)> 1000 && b+c< 2000)
        return "colonial";
    else if( (b+c) > 0 && (b+c) < 1000)
        return "roman";
    else if( (b+c) < 0)
        return "medieval";
    else
        return "fail";

}


function intro(sum, friend):String
{
    return "Once upon a time, in the year "+ b+c +", "+friend;
}

function body(year):String
{
    if ("future")
        return " saw a flying saucer and descided they wanted do be an alien.";
    else if ("colonial")
        return " just got off the the Mayflower and descided they wanted to eat some turkey.";
    else if ("roman")
        return " are taking a break after a fierce battle with the Romans.";
    else if ("medieval")
        return " saved the princess in shining armor after slaying the dragon.";
    else if ("fail")
        return " just got an F on their exam.";
    else
        return " just got an F on their test.";            
}
trace (b+c);
trace(intro(sum, friend(d, a)) + body(year));
```

Comment: Pasting your code in a clean FLA yields `"roman"` for the year function (with parameters 50 and 6). Are you sure something else isn't in play?

Comment: If I copy paste the code exactly into flash, I get "Once upon a time, in the year 506, Kyle and Tim saw a flying saucer and descided they wanted do be an alien."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing functions as parameters to other functions. You need to pass the result of a function call as parameters to the other functions.

Also, if you use int+int in a string concatination, you need to put that calculation between brackets. So use (int+int) instead.

In the intro function, you passed in the sum as a parameter, but did not use it. Instead you recalculated b+c.

Try this:

```
var a:String = "Tim";
var b:int = 50; //CHANGE TO ANY INT YOU WANT
var c:int = 6; //CHANGE TO ANY INT YOU WANT
var d:String = "Kyle";
var sum:int = b+c;

function friend(d:String, a:String):String
{
    return d+" and "+a;
}

function year(b:int, c:int):String
{
    if( (b+c) > 2000 )
        return "future";
    else if( (b+c)> 1000 && b+c< 2000)
        return "colonial";
    else if( (b+c) > 0 && (b+c) < 1000)
        return "roman";
    else if( (b+c) < 0)
        return "medieval";
    else
        return "fail";

}


function intro(sum:int, friend:String):String
{
    return "Once upon a time, in the year "+ sum +", "+friend;
}

function body(year:String):String
{
    if ("future")
        return " saw a flying saucer and descided they wanted do be an alien.";
    else if ("colonial")
        return " just got off the the Mayflower and descided they wanted to eat some turkey.";
    else if ("roman")
        return " are taking a break after a fierce battle with the Romans.";
    else if ("medieval")
        return " saved the princess in shining armor after slaying the dragon.";
    else if ("fail")
        return " just got an F on their exam.";
    else
        return " just got an F on their test.";            
}
trace (b+c);
trace(intro(sum, friend(d, a)) + body(year(b, c)));
```

Comment: It's nice of you to solve the problem for him, but you should add some explanation of what you changed - otherwise it will be hard for others to follow this question and answer.

Comment: Right, I added the solution first and added comments later on. You must have read the answer just in between.

Comment: I used diff to see the differences; helped a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of your if/else structure:

```
function body(year:String):String
{
    switch(year)
    {
        case "future":
        return " saw a flying saucer and descided they wanted do be an alien.";
        break;
        case "colonial":
        return " just got off the the Mayflower and descided they wanted to eat some turkey.";
        break;
        case "roman":
        return " are taking a break after a fierce battle with the Romans.";
        break;
        case "medieval":
        return " saved the princess in shining armor after slaying the dragon.";
        break;
        case "fail":
        return " just got an F on their exam.";
        break;
        default:
        return " just got an F on their test."; 
        break;
    }
}
```

You weren't exactly checking against the parameter, so it defaulted to "future" every time. It works with this function supplanting the previous version.